# controlling threads flow

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, multitasking

I had a task to write simple game simulating two players picking up 1-3 matches one after another until the pile is gone. I managed to do it for computer choosing random value of matches but now I'd like to go further and allow humans to play the game. Here's what I already have : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/201761/

Class Player is a computer player, and PlayerMan should be human being. Problem is, that thread of PlayerMan should wait until proper value of matches is given but I cannot make it work this way. Logic is as follows: thread runs until matches equals to zero. If player number is correct at the moment function pickMatches() is called. After decreasing number of matches on table, thread should wait and another thread should be notified. I know I must use wait() and notify() but I can't place them right.
Class Shared keeps the value of current player, and also amount of matches.

```
public void suspendThread() {
    suspended = true;
}

public void resumeThread() {
    suspended = false;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    int matches=1;
    int which = 0;
    int tmp=0;
    Shared data = this.selectData();
    String name = this.returnName();
    int number = this.getNumber();

    while(data.getMatches() != 0){

        while(!suspended){

            try{             
                which = data.getCurrent();

                if(number == which){

                    matches = pickMatches();

                    tmp = data.getMatches() - matches;
                    data.setMatches(tmp, number);

                    if(data.getMatches() == 0){
                        System.out.println("                          "+
                            name+" takes "+matches+" matches.");
                        System.out.println("Winner is player: "+name);
                        stop();
                    }

                    System.out.println("                          "+
                            name+" takes "+matches+" matches.");

                    if(number != 0){
                        data.setCurrent(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        data.setCurrent(1);
                    }
                }
                this.suspendThread();
                notifyAll();
                wait();

            }catch(InterruptedException exc) {}    
        }
    }
}

@Override
synchronized public int pickMatches(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    Shared data = this.selectData();

    System.out.println("Choose amount of matches (from 1 to 3): ");

        if(data.getMatches() == 1){
            System.out.println("There's only 1 match left !");
            while(n != 1){
                n = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        else{
            do{
                n = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            while(n <= 1 && n >= 3);
        }
    return n;
}
```

}

Comment: @owca too much code! Try to make it more compliant with Short Self-Contained Compilable Example (sscce): http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to do it without wait() etc.

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/201966/

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me first say that I think you are making this hardier than you need to. If it were me, I would create a 'GameMaster' class whose job it is to loop and tell each player when their turn comes up. Your player classes wouldn't have loops, just a takeTurn method. This way you can remove the waiting/notifying behavior from your player classes.

If you wish to keep the design you have, I would still get rid of the wait/notify and use a [Semaphore](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Check the docs for proper usage, but the gist is that you would remove the suspend/resume methods and have a acquire() call at the top of your loop and release at the bottom. Just make sure fairness is set to true in the constructor, that way you won't have to worry about a player taking two turns in a row by acquiring the semaphore lock twice in a row.

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself having to set up communication between threads to synchronize their execution, just so that a specified sequence of events takes place (such as taking turns playing a game), it's a good sign that you may have more threads than you need.

In this case, consider a single thread that executes a takeTurn() method on various extensions of a Player class might make life easier for you.  You could make Player an abstract base class that mandates .takeTurn(), then have HumanPlayer and MachinePlayer classes encapsulate the code that makes sense for each type of player inside that method.  This should make extension to larger numbers of players relatively trivial as compared to lots of wait() and notify().